# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'connection.connect')

Tags: javascript, html, sql, node.js

I get this error when trying to call sql connect in node. Here is the node function:

```
function fetchSql() {
    console.log(sqlResult);
        console.log("Inside fetchSql");
        document.getElementById('MixLabel').innerHTML = sqlResult;

    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
                console.error('Database connection failed: ' + err.stack);
                return;
        }

    connection.query("select * from users where username = 'maxolgin';", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        sqlResult = result[0].username;
        console.log(sqlResult);
    });

    console.log('Connected to database.');
});

}
```

Here is the html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../app.js"></script>

<div class="ProfileImage" onmouseover="fetchSql()" onclick="fetchSql()"> </div>
```

Why when I mouseover or click on the ProfileImage class do I get `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'connection.connect')`

What do I need to change to be allowed to run connection.connect inside a function in js?

Comment: Is the `fetchSql()` code in the front-end or back-end? Where is `connection` defined? Please be aware: If this is front-end code it allows arbitrary SQL injection which is an extreme security vulnerability.

Comment: This is on my server on the back-end